# So what does Cyanogen Inc shutting down mean for CyanogenMod and similar ROMs?

Tags: cyanogenmod, cyanogen-os

So Cyanogen Inc (cyngn), known for their support for their support for CyanogenMod and their efforts to integrate Cyanogen OS into devices such as the OnePlus One, Alcatel POP Mirage, and [several other devices](https://cyngn.com/get-cyanogen-os). Cyanogen Inc just recently [announced that they are shutting down their services](https://cyngn.com/blog/cyanogen-services-shutting-down).

What does this mean for CyanogenMod, Cyanogen OS, and the devices which originally shipped with Cyanogen OS? Will they no longer receive OTA updates?

Comment: How will you get an OTA update if the servers providing it are taken down, and no new updates are being made in the first place?

Comment: Well Matthew, there's several things that phone manufacturers can presumably do, and I assume that one of those may be to redirect the updater to a new location.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CM's own blog is [unreachable](https://twitter.com/CyanogenMod/status/813086249506349056) now, but [XDA-Developers](https://www.xda-developers.com/the-death-of-cyangenmod-and-whats-in-store-for-the-future/) already summed it up and clarified some important bits:

- All monetary and infrastructural support for CyanogenMod from Cyanogen Inc. will cease. -> CyanogenMod will no longer receive nightly builds after December 31st... unless the team [finds another host](http://lineageos.org/Infrastructure-Status-and-Official-Builds/) to build nightlies.
- CyanogenMod will rebrand as LineageOS.
- The CyanogenMod team will not continue official development on the CyanogenMod project, but the work will continue in LineageOS.

Since it's clear that Cyngn is going in a new direction, Cyanogen OS will almost certainly have no future - it's not community-driven in the first place. CyanogenMod, on the other hand, will live a bit longer, until Lineage truly dawns (or fails).

**UPDATE** Dec 29, 2016: The [GitHub repo](https://github.com/lineageos) and [Gerrit code review platform](https://review.lineageos.org/#/q/status:open) of LineageOS are online, and I have personally [verified](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=70290890&postcount=224) that codes are fully buildable, and previous CM users can seamlessly transition to current builds. Also, from what the Gerrit shows, the team is now working on renaming all CM elements to Lineage/LineageOS, amongst the usual bug fixes and improvements.

**UPDATE** Jan 13, 2017: Rebadging is almost complete: LineageOS 14.1 now has a redesigned setup wizard with no CyanogenMod presence. LineageOS 13 remains mostly untouched, since Marshmallow is near deprecation. The [download site](https://download.lineageos.org/) itself is also accessible, though building has yet to begin.

**UPDATE** Jan 18, 2017: LineageOS now has its own [bootanimation](https://review.lineageos.org/#/c/156893/), thus rebadging can be deemed as completed.

**UPDATE** Jan 23, 2017: [All systems operational](http://lineageos.org/Update-and-Build-Prep/), and first official builds have [rolled out](https://download.lineageos.org/)!

Comment: Update - I moved from CM to lineageos builds about 3 months ago (Feb 2017). Its stable, the big stuff works, and overall works well enough to be a daily phone OS, although some (mostly minor) issues.